# passing data to a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my button function where I pass the data.

The problem is Area and Country details are passed to the next ViewController but latitude and longitude return null.

**In ViewController.m :**

```
- (IBAction)forecast:(UIButton *)sender
{
    ForecastViewController *sendDetails = [[ForecastViewController alloc] init];
    NSArray *seperate = [full componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
    Area = seperate[0];
    Country = seperate[1];
    sendDetails.Area = Area;
    sendDetails.Country = Country;
    NSLog(@"%@%@",self.longitude,self.latitude);
    NSString *lt = self.latitude;
    NSString *ln = self.longitude;
    sendDetails.longitude = lt;
    sendDetails.latitude = ln;
}
```

**In ForecastViewController.h**

```
//
//  ForecastViewController.h
//  Weather App
//
//  Created by Mac-Mini-2 on 10/02/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Mac-Mini-2. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <Reachability.h>

@interface ForecastViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *place;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

@property NSString *Area;
@property NSString *Country;
@property NSString *latitude;
@property NSString *longitude;

@end
```

**In ForecastViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.table.delegate = self;
    self.table.dataSource = self;
    self.place.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",self.Area,self.Country];
    locationName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",self.Area,self.Country];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    metric = [defaults boolForKey:@"metric"];
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NSInteger x = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (x > 0)
    {
        reachable = YES;
        NSLog(@"%@, %@",self.latitude,self.longitude);
        [self getForecast:self.latitude longitudes:self.longitude];

    }
    else
    {
        reachable = NO;
        [self getData];
        errorMsg = @"Because of unavailability of Network Realtime information wont be available.";
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayAlert) withObject:NULL waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
    [reach startNotifier];
}
```

Please let me know where I could have gone wrong here.
I checked by logging the data onto console. The area and country is printed but longitude and latitude give null values.

Comment: You're not showing us where/how you set the longitude and latitude.

Comment: i was printing them to see if they contain data... and to make sure i m not passing nil values..
and they are not.. i have checked the values too...
as i said area and country get passed but the other two dont...i m confused

Comment: i have edited my question u can see where i am sending them now

Comment: Where are you setting the latitude and longitude

Comment: in the method
**- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations** 
and they are getting set i have logged them in the function above.

Comment: There's obviously something missing in your code... In the `forecast:` method, you allocate a `ForecastViewController`, set some of its properties, then don't do anything with it (so it's discarded). Where/how do you present the new view controller? Wouldn't you be using a segue in your storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing a push to ForecastViewController, maybe implementing `prepareForSegue:sender:` is your best option.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"viewForecast"]){

    NSArray *seperate = [full componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
    Area = seperate[0];
    Country = seperate[1];        
        [(ForecastViewController *) [segue destinationViewController] setArea:area];
[(ForecastViewController *) [segue destinationViewController] setCountry:country];
...
...
    }
}
```

Comment: any idea how only area and country are working and the other two are not?

Comment: those were missing, `[(ForecastViewController *) [segue destinationViewController] setLongitude:lt];
[(ForecastViewController *) [segue destinationViewController] setLatitude:ln];`

Comment: you must also, add the segue on your storyboard

Comment: rightnow i am doing the action using only segues i havent used anything else other than the IBAction button. and it does go to the next view and print the details except latitude and longitude.

Comment: maybe changing your properties to @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *latitude;

Answer (score 0):

Could I the that latitude and longitude are stored as numbers in the first controller?   Are you sure that 'sendDetails.latitude' and 'longitude' are set correctly in 'ViewController'?

Comment: i have converted lat and long into strings and then passed them even that doesnt seem to work.
yes.. else NSLog wouldnt giveme the result it prints all details area country lat and long in my ViewController.h, however in ForecastViewController it prints only area and country

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to edit two point firstly in ForecastViewController.h set

```
@property (Strong, nonatomic) NSString *Area;
@property (Strong, nonatomic) NSString *Country;
@property (Strong, nonatomic) NSString *latitude;
@property (Strong, nonatomic) NSString *longitude;
```

and @synthsize it in ForecastViewController.m.
secondly:-

```
  - (IBAction)forecast:(UIButton *)sender
    {


     ForecastViewController *sendDetails = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"your ForecastViewController name in storyboard"];
    NSArray *seperate = [full componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
    Area = seperate[0];
    Country = seperate[1];
    sendDetails.Area = Area;
    sendDetails.Country = Country;
    NSLog(@"%@%@",self.longitude,self.latitude);
    NSString *lt = self.latitude;
    NSString *ln = self.longitude;
    sendDetails.longitude = lt;
    sendDetails.latitude = ln;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sendDetails animated:YES];
}
```